# jQuery copying style to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my problem is the following:

I have something like this HTML CODE:

```
<div class="rsContent">
  <div class="rsImg" style="width:900px;height:900px; margin-left:-450px; margin-top: -450px;"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock"></div>
</div>
<div class="rsContent">
  <div class="rsImg" style="width:1200px;height:1200px; margin-left:-600px; margin-top: -600px;"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock"></div>
</div>
```

So what I want to do is take the style Attribute of the `.rsImg` Container and place It in the `.rsABBlock` elements underneath the `.rsImg` but only for those that are in the same `.rsContent` Container

So after the code I am looking for is run the result should look like this:

```
<div class="rsContent">
  <div class="rsImg" style="width:900px;height:900px; margin-left:-450px; margin-top: -450px;"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock" style="width:900px;height:900px; margin-left:-450px; margin-top: -450px;"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock" style="width:900px;height:900px; margin-left:-450px; margin-top: -450px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="rsContent">
  <div class="rsImg" style="width:1200px;height:1200px; margin-left:-600px; margin-top: -600px;"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock" style="width:1200px;height:1200px; margin-left:-600px; margin-top: -600px;"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock" style="width:1200px;height:1200px; margin-left:-600px; margin-top: -600px;"></div>
  <div class="rsABBlock" style="width:1200px;height:1200px; margin-left:-600px; margin-top: -600px;"></div>
</div>
```

The code I want to have only needs to be executed once.
This is what I tried

```
jQuery(".rsContent").each(function(){
    var style_var = jQuery(".rsImg").attr("style");
    jQuery(".rsABBlock").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr("style",style_var);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you show the jQuery you've tried?

Comment: I thought something like this would do it...:

`jQuery(".rsContent").each(function(){    
 var style_var = jQuery("rsImg").attr("style");    
 jQuery(".rsABBlock").each(function(){    
 jQuery(this).attr("style",style_var);    
 });`

Comment: You were missing a period in `.find(".rsImg")` and all you needed to do was target those elements within the one in the `each` loop by using `jQuery(this).find()` . rynhe has almost given you the answer but missed the period as you did. Working version http://jsfiddle.net/Pj8mY/

Comment: Can you correct him and post as answer... because I don't really see where he is missing something...

and his code breaks all the code underneath....

Comment: Sure, i posted a revised answer and a shorter solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(".rsContent").each(function(){    
    var style_var = jQuery(this).find(".rsImg").attr("style");   
    jQuery(this).find(".rsABBlock").each(function(){     
        jQuery(this).attr("style",style_var);    
    }); 
})
```

You have to add `this`.... `jQuery(this).find`

Comment: You're missing a period `.find(".rsImg")`. Here's a working version http://jsfiddle.net/Pj8mY/

Comment: I see that it should work... but somehow It breaks my codes underneath...

Do you want to see the Website?

Comment: NP. OP missed the `.`, he's updated the question since.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with less code

```
    jQuery(".rsImg").each(function(){    
        jQuery(this).siblings().attr('style', jQuery(this).attr("style"));
        // or if there are other siblings and you need to specify rsABBlock
        // jQuery(this).siblings(".rsABBlock").attr('style', jQuery(this).attr("style"));
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pj8mY/1/

But to debug your original, you were missing a period in `.find(".rsImg")` and all you needed to do was target those child elements of the one in the `each` loop by using `jQuery(this).find()`

```
    jQuery(".rsContent").each(function(){    
        var style_var = jQuery(this).find(".rsImg").attr("style");
        jQuery(this).find(".rsABBlock").each(function(){     
            jQuery(this).attr("style",style_var);    
        }); 
    })
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pj8mY/

Answer (score 0):

Your inner ".rsABBlock" should start from the current ".rsImg" that you are itereating.

```
jQuery("div.rsContent > div.rsImg").each(function () { //Get DIV with class .rsImg which is the child of a DIV with class .rsContent
    var style_var = jQuery(this).attr("style");
    jQuery(this).siblings("div.rsABBlock").each(function () { //Iterate through the siblings, not all .rsABBlock. 
        jQuery(this).attr("style", style_var);
    });
});
```

If all you want is just replacing the style, you don't need to use ".each" in the inner loop. Just use ".attr". It will be called for all selected element.

```
jQuery("div.rsContent > div.rsImg").each(function () { //Get DIV with class .rsImg which is the child of a DIV with class .rsContent
    var style_var = jQuery(this).attr("style");
    jQuery(this).siblings("div.rsABBlock").attr("style", style_var);
});
```

Comment: - Making your jQuery selections stricter avoid future unexpected problem. Simply use jQuery(".rsABBlock") will select all other elements even it's outside the target DIV (".rsContent")

Comment: - Regarding @rynhe's solution, it will work if you don't loop through ".rsContent", but through ".rsImg" instead.